# How to localize Gitkit login button & login page

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

The sample code below is for the old V1 version only. Is there any new solution recommended? Thanks.

```
google.load('identitytoolkit', '0.1', {packages: ['ac'], language: 'fr'});
```

Answer (score 2):

for the latest v3 identity toolkit client, the above code will not work. Internationalization and localization for v3 will be available in the very near future.